# How to merge multiple CSV files in R that begging with the same number, 400 times

Tags: r, csv

I am new to both **R** and stackoverflow. I have searched some other questions, but found nothing. Forgive me if this has already been answered.

I have multiple csv files that belong to one individual. They are named like this: `304_0001, 304_0002... 304_0010`. In the SAME folder I have multiple individuals, so right after `304` I have `378_0001...378_0010`.

My issue is that I will have 400 individuals, each with 10 csv files, all in one folder. I need help in how I could merge each of those 10 files that belong to just one. And if there were a way so that I did not have to write that code 400 times while altering the name, that would be beautiful.

Thank you all so much for your time!

Answer (score 1):

We can do

```
files <- list.files(path = path_to_folder,  pattern = ".csv", full.names = TRUE)
v1 <- basename(files)
l1 <- split(v1, sub("_.*", "", v1))
res <- lapply(l1, function(file) Reduce(function(...) 
         merge(..., by = 'idcol'), lapply(file, read.csv, header= TRUE)))
```

NOTE: It is not clear about the merging column, so here we specify it as `idcol`

If we need to `rbind` the datasets

```
res <- lapply(l1, function(file) do.call(rbind, lapply(file, read.csv header=TRUE)))
```

Comment: I think he says `merge` but wants to `rbind`